# Python nested loops, a little understanding needed

Tags: python, for-loop, syntax

Please see the below code

```
def common_letters(string_one,string_two):
    letters_in_common = []
    for letter in string_one:
        for letter2 in string_two:
            if letter == letter2:
                letters_in_common.append(letter)
                return letters_in_common

returned = common_letters("hello", "loha")
print(returned)
```

The above code works, but only on the first iteration of the outer loop, hence my letters_in_common list only returns `['h']` when it should return `['h','l','l']`, In JS the syntax is different and the loop works incrementally.

Am I misunderstanding how loops work in Python or is there a syntax level step I have not included?

p.s. I am aware that I could use the 'in' keyword etc but I wanted to try it with a loop first.

Comment: In JS, the curly braces do the work of indentation. If your `if` statements don't have `{ ... }` braces then only *one* statement is part of the block. Any indentation in JS code *doesn't count the way it does in Python*.

Comment: In other words: the `return` is probably **not part of the loops**

Comment: Thank you @MartijnPieters Getting used to indentation lines!

Answer (score 3):

Your `return` is indented so that it is inside `if`. Presumably you want to return after you check every letter against every letter, which means `return` has to be outside the loops:

```
def common_letters(string_one, string_two):
    letters_in_common = []
    for letter in string_one:
        for letter2 in string_two:
            if letter == letter2:
                letters_in_common.append(letter)
    return letters_in_common
```

Sidenote: This will give a somewhat surprising result if there are multiples of a shared letter in both strings. If I wanted to find out just the shared letters, I would use set intersection:

```
def common_letters(string_one, string_two):
    return list(set(string_one) & set(string_two))
```

Comment: Thanks, make sense and it is now working fine. May take me a little time to get used to indentation lines!